# The server exited prematurely with exit code 1 GlassFish 4

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-4, asadmin

I've been trying to start the glassfish server domain with the following command `asadmin start-domain domain1` but the result wasn't the expected. This what the outputs is throwing out:

```
Waiting for domain1 to start .Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.

Command start-domain failed.
```

Btw I've already tried changing the network-listener-port number located inside glassfish folders **C:\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml**  from port `8080` to `4949` and it didn't work. Besides I also tried running the `start-domain domain1` command in the asadmin batch file and nothing happened, the output still the same.

Any idea how can I fix this out?

Comment: I have the same problem right now. Could you please share the solution that you found?

Comment: Sorry for replying this late. Being honest I couldn't find a solution to this, I just moved to Ubuntu, and glassfish there run pretty good. Did u find any solution?

Comment: It took me awhile but I finally tried to start it with asadmin.sh and it worked - on Windows 10...

Comment: Ohhh good, I did the same, I mean I ran the start domain command with asadmind bash file but It didn't work for me. But I'm glad it did for you. Could u please post your solution in this post? so others could have a reference about what worked for u

Answer (score 0):

I tried to start it with asadmin.sh and it worked on Windows 10